# How do I configure Aperture to upload image location information to Facebook?

Tags: photos, facebook, aperture, gps

All of the discussion I can find online suggests that an image in Aperture with location information that is uploaded to Facebook (using Aperture's Facebook integration) should have a location assigned in Facebook. But all my attempts to get image location information from Aperture to Facebook have failed.

How do I configure Aperture to upload image location information to Facebook? Is this feature in fact supported?

---

Note that the [Aperture Export setting](http://documentation.apple.com/en/aperture/usermanual/index.html#chapter=28&section=2&hash=apple_ref%3adoc%3auid%3aAperture-UserManual-CH5-SW300) to allow export of location information is enabled.

Comment: did you find any answer to this? I am having the same problem and could use some pointers... Facebook doesn't seem to read any location data from Aperture

Comment: What version of aperture and what version of OSX?

Comment: @bmike: Was 10.8 and whatever version of Aperture was current prior to the latest. Hold on and let me confirm that this persists with 10.9.

Comment: @bmike: Continues in 10.9 / 3.5.